# Coldfusion: How does the cfcatch.ErrNumber work?

Tags: coldfusion

How does ColdFusion assign an error number/value to cfcatch.ErrNumber?  I know I have to place it within a cftry/cfcatch tags.  When an error is caught, I can use cfcatch.message or cfcatch.detail to see what happened but if I try to access cfcatch.ErrNumber, I get an error.  How do you implement it?  CFDOCS were of no use.

Not a big deal, just wondering.

```
<cftry>
<cfquery name='somequery' datasource='dsn'>
    select foo1, foo2, foo3
    from footable XXX
</cfquery>
<cfcatch type='any'>
    <cfoutput>#cfcatch.message#</cfquery>
</cftry>
```

The snippet above would come back and say something about table not found since I added the XXX after the table name.  Where would cfcatch.ErrNumber come into play here?

Comment: You can throw your own custom exception with your custom error code using <cfthrow>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't seeing it because errNumber is only a valid attribute of cfcatch when the error is of type "expression".  From the [docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_c_04.html):

> cfcatch.ErrNumber
>   Applies to type = "expression". Internal expression error number.

So you would have to change your code to something like this:

```
<cftry>
<cfquery name='somequery' datasource='dsn'>
    select foo1, foo2, foo3
    from footable XXX
</cfquery>
    <cfcatch type='expression'>
        <cfoutput>#cfcatch.errNumber#</cfoutput>
    </cfcatch>
    <cfcatch type='any'>
    <cfoutput>#cfcatch.message#</cfoutput>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't associate type="expression" to the type of catch... I did actually read that but I did not connect the dots (I must not have been paying attention to what I was reading because it sure is clear this morning.  :)  Thanks

Comment: It might be simpler to do a <cfdump> of #cfcatch#, that way you don't have to worry about which members the structure will have.

Comment: @DavidFaber that does assume that all you really want to do with the error is output it.

Comment: Sure. :) Another option might be to do a structKeyExists() on the cfcatch structure. Not that your method isn't great, just pointing out that there are alternatives.